# Failed to load module for Taiko on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: ubuntu, npm, raspberry-pi

I am having a difficulty installing and running Taiko on a Raspberry Pi 4. I have tried installing Taiko via NPM on both 32 and 64 bit version of Ubuntu with the same error. Please advise.

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 4
OS: Ubuntu 19.10.1 32 bit

**Installation process:**

sudo apt-get install chromium-browser

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo -E bash –

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

sudo npm install npm --global

mkdir ~/.npm-global

npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'

export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

source ~/.profile

sudo chown ubuntu:root -R /usr/lib/node_modules/

TAIKO_BROWSER_PATH=$(/usr/bin/chromium-browser) npm install -g taiko

Gtk-Message: 20:21:52.302: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Gtk-Message: 20:21:52.305: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

[17273:17273:0116/202153.078498:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(372)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.

[17304:7:0116/202153.831615:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(124)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.

[17304:1:0116/202154.631772:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.

[17304:1:0116/202154.633083:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.

[17032:17267:0116/202157.585984:ERROR:udev_watcher.cc(94)] Failed to begin udev enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

Set `TAIKO_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD` to true for skipping default chromium download during installation, then provide `TAIKO_BROWSER_PATH=$(/usr/bin/chromium-browser)` when launching taiko.

For running in headless mode in raspberry pass args `'--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'` to `openBrowser`

```
await openBrowser({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
```